# Connecting PyQt button click event to a separate function in a different module for Blender Tools

Tags: python

So I have created a PyQT tool but now I am trying to segregate it to make it easily readable,earlier I had pyqt UI class, all functions within it in a single module and I was using blender operator to run the eventloop for pyqt.

What I have right now is :

```
operators.py

import bpy
from blender_common.core import QtWindowEventLoop
from model_publish_tool.ui.ui import ModelPublishToolUI

class ModelPublishWindowOperator(QtWindowEventLoop):
    bl_idname = 'model_publish_tool.window'
    bl_label = 'Model Publish'

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(ModelPublishToolUI)

class ModelPublishToolSubMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_idname = 'model_publish_sub_menu.window'
    bl_label = "Model Publish Tools"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator('model_publish_tool.window')
```

---

```
ui.py


import bpy
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QGroupBox, QListWidget,QListWidgetItem

# from qc_extend.ui.ui import QCValidationWidget

class ModelPublishToolUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ModelPublishToolUI, self).__init__()
        self.setObjectName('QcTool')
        self.setWindowTitle('QC Tool')
        self.setGeometry(75, 250, 250, 75)
        self.failed_valid_list  = []
        self.failed_valid_list_1 = []
        self.main_layout = None
        self.initUI()
        self.cmd = None

    def initUI(self):
        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.btn_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.qc_validation_btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.qc_validation_btn.setText("QC Validation")
        self.qc_validation_btn.clicked.connect(self.show_qc_validation_layout)
        self.btn_layout.addWidget(self.qc_validation_btn)

        self.turn_around_btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.turn_around_btn.setText("Turn Around")
        self.turn_around_btn.clicked.connect(self.turnaround)
        self.btn_layout.addWidget(self.turn_around_btn)

        self.publish_btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.publish_btn.setText("Publish Asset")
        self.publish_btn.clicked.connect(self.show_publish_layout)
        self.btn_layout.addWidget(self.publish_btn)
        self.btn_container = QWidget(self)
        self.btn_container.setLayout(self.btn_layout)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.btn_container)
        self.show()



   def show_qc_validation_layout():
     /* code snippet */
   def show_publish_layout():
     /* code snippet */
   def turnaround():
     /* code snippet */
```

Now I what I am looking for is:
creating two modules `connections.py` and `functions.py`

where `connection.py` will be something like this as follows:

```
from functools import partial
from model_publish_tool.functions.functions import (turnaround,)
from model_publish_tool.ui.ui import ModelPublishToolUI

def update_ui_data():
    ui_obj = ModelPublishToolUI()

    ui_obj.qc_validation_btn.clicked.connect(partial(turnaround.show_validation_layout))
    ui_obj.qc_validation_btn.clicked.connect(partial(turnaround.turnaround))
    ui_obj.qc_validation_btn.clicked.connect(partial(turnaround.show_publish_layout))
```

and `functions.py` will consists of all the required functions

I have a issue now how should i go for `connections.py` execution

As I am beginner to blender so i don't know much about `operators` scope and usecases and I can't find anything on module execution using operators

1. Is there anyway I can do it using operator class itself ?
2. Or any other alternate way.

I might be missing something, but any help would be really great

Thanks & Regards